# From few days Facebook events list not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using core php and facebook sdk to get facebook events list. It was working very well but from recently it seems not getting the lists of events.

I'm using this code to get event list:

```
$userProfile = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture,events');
$fbuser = $userProfile->getDecodedBody();
```

I get all the information like `"id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture"` but now I don't get only `events`!

If anyone have an idea about this or have faced the same issue, please help me!!

Also, if anyone want to more details about code please post your comments.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

Comment: @CBroe: Actually i have requested for `user_events` permission but it was not approved.After than i have proper drop question in direct support of facebook but didn't get any reply.